# How would a database be created using clojure's java.jdbc?

Tags: jdbc, clojure

I want to be able to write the following functions for jdbc:

```
(def db {:classname "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
         :subprotocol "mysql"
         :subname "//127.0.0.1:3306/santacsv"
         :server "//127.0.0.1:3306"
         :schema "santa"
         :user "root"
         :password "root"})

(defn has-schema? [db & [schema]])

(defn create-schema [db & [schema]])

(defn drop-schema [db & [schema]])
```

I'm not sure how to go about it. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented my own here:

https://github.com/zcaudate/manas/blob/master/src/manas/core.clj

```
    (defmacro run-statement [env database body catch-body & [statement]]
      `(do (Class/forName (:classname ~env))
           (let [~'conn (atom nil)]
             (try
               (reset! ~'conn (DriverManager/getConnection
                              (str "jdbc:" (:subprotocol ~env) ":"
                                   (:server ~env) "/" (or ~database (:database ~env)))
                              (:user ~env)
                              (:password ~env)))
               ~@(if statement
                   [(list 'let '[stmt (.createStatement @conn)]
                          (list '.executeUpdate 'stmt statement))])
               ~@body
               (catch SQLException ~'e
                 ~@catch-body)
               (finally
                 (if-not (nil? (deref ~'conn))
                   (.close (deref ~'conn))))))))

    (defn has-connection? [env & [url]]
      (let [env (if url (assoc env :server url) env)]
        (run-statement env "" (true) (false))))

    (defn all-databases [env]
      (run-statement env ""
                     ((let [rs (.getCatalogs (.getMetaData @conn))]
                        (loop [rs rs acc []]
                          (if (.next rs)
                            (recur rs (conj acc (.getString rs "TABLE_CAT")))
                            acc))))
                     ()))

    (defn has-database? [env & [schema]]
      (run-statement env schema (true) (false)))

    (defn create-database [env & [schema]]
      (run-statement env ""
                     (true)
                     (false)
                     (str "create database " (or schema (:database env)))))

    (defn drop-database [env & [schema]]
      (run-statement env ""
                     (true)
                     (false)
                     (str "drop database " (or schema (:database env)))))
```

Answer (score 1):

At a minimum, you could use [clojure.java.jdbc](https://github.com/clojure/java.jdbc) and write the corresponding SQL to `execute!`.

Alternatively, I would consider using a dedicated migrations library/framework.  [flyway](http://flywaydb.org/) is java-based and has a java-api which you could call with interop.

Finally, there are a few clojure-based migrations libraries like [lobos](https://github.com/budu/lobos), but I can't speak to their maturity, so your mileage may very.